# ng-class not working in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-class that doesn't seem to be adding the class on initial load. It looks like the function is working perfectly, and outputting the proper boolean, but the class just doesn't add. However if I toggle the value, it then updates as expected.

```
<ul class="gb-talents-tiers">
  <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="tier in guide.tiers()">
    <span>{{tier}}</span>
    <ul class="gb-talents-icons clearfix">
      <li ng-repeat="talent in guide.talentsByTier(hero.hero, tier) | orderBy: talent.orderNum">
        <a href="#" class="talents-icon {{hero.hero.className}} {{talent.className}}" ng-class="{ 'tier-selected': guide.hasAnyTalent(hero, talent), 'active': guide.hasTalent(hero, talent) }" ng-click="guide.toggleTalent(hero, talent)" hots-talent>{{talent.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem lies with:

```
ng-class="{ 'tier-selected': guide.hasAnyTalent(hero, talent), 'active': guide.hasTalent(hero, talent) }"
```

Everything is outputting as expected except for the classes being added on inital load. When I output "{{guide.hasTalent(hero, talent)}}", it returns true or false as expected. If you need more info, I will do my best.

Edit: Adding hasTalent function

```
gb.hasTalent = function (hero, talent) {
  if (hero.talents['tier'+talent.tier] === talent._id) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Added a plunkr, which seems to work perfectly. FML.
http://plnkr.co/edit/B8bUm5wD5FtkyFkOJfWr?p=preview

Comment: Well, a simple fix would be to run the function before angular sees and calculates the result, then save the result to an attribute of the object being repeated, that way you are doing pre-processing which will be visible right away.  Else, what you are setting yourself up for is lots of very slow processing with lots of watchers firing a whole lot.

Comment: could you please setup a plnkr/jsfiddle?

Comment: In your ng-repeat you're passing the `hero` object a lot. Apparently it's static and is the same for every iteration, so why pass it in a function? Also, where/when is it initialized?

Comment: It's looping through a hero array as well.

Comment: are you using `controllerAs`? are you getting any console error?

Comment: Not using controllerAs, no console errors.

Comment: could we get code of `hasTalent()` method

Comment: If this is a nested ng-repeat, then @Deblaton's answer is correct, but you need `$parent.$parent.guide.hasAnyTalent(hero, talent)`

Comment: Yes $parent.$parent would make more sense..I think

Comment: I tried from 1 $parent to 4 $parents, it is not working.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Inspect the `a` tag, and then look at the scope in the AngularJS tab of the console. The problem is most likely you are trying to use a function in the wrong scope. You just need to find out where it is.

Comment: Crap, I setup a plunkr, and it is working fine there. http://plnkr.co/edit/B8bUm5wD5FtkyFkOJfWr?p=preview

Comment: what does this `hots-talent` attribute does?

Comment: Provides a hover modal with info.

Comment: btw you can replace your 4 lines of if true/else false code with `return (hero.talents['tier'+talent.tier] === talent._id)`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that when I posted it ... OCD ftw.

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration of ng-repeat creates a new scope.

So, if you want to access a property from a parent scope, you need to do this :

```
ng-class="{ 'tier-selected': $parent.guide.hasAnyTalent(hero, talent),
```